# Centering div inside a div and make the text get smaller to screen proportion

Tags: html, css

I want to center all the div's so when screen get smaller it stay centered and just get smaller

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6253/1/

the code example:

```
#first_section {
   width: 0 auto;
   height: 776px;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;



}

#square {
   width: 857px;
   height: 4px;
   background-color: #2a2d2f;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#first_section_txt {
   position: relative;
   width: 997px;
   height: 164px;
   margin-left: 500px;
   margin-top: 251px;
}

.clear_both {
   clear: both;
}

h1 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #4a4949;
     }
h2 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #c0c0c0;
     }
h3 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    padding-left: 350px;
    top: 15px;
     }

     h3{
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.37);
     }
#first_section img {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: 525px;
   width: 466px;
   height: 540px;
   margin-top: -150px;

}
```

Comment: What's the square for?

Comment: You need to set you widths to percentages and then add either 'text-align:center;' or

Comment: 'margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;' to your inside div. You should also set your fonts to ems so that the user can scale it themselves. You should use percentages for your fonts to become smaller when the screen size becomes smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a new trick i discovered here there are more tricks, links below, but before all tricks lets take a look at this **Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/h6253/9/

Also, to make it responsive you need to use max/min-width property.

Code:

```
div {
    height: 200px; background-color: rgb(0, 184, 255); color:white;
    font-family:sans-serif; padding:20px;
    min-width: 200px; max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;    
}
```

**The method i used**: 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

**other methods**...

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ (**new in css**)

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a responsive page that resizes based on screen size, you have to use percentages for the `div` elements and em values for the text. To center the `div` elements you add `margin:0 auto;`.

I stripped all of the other css stuff you had going on there and I left the basic stuff you need to get what you want. You can style it however you'd like now.

[CLICK HERE FOR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h6253/4/)

```
#first_section{
width:100%;
height:px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:0 auto;
min-width:320px;
}
#first_section_txt{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
font-size:2em;
word-wrap:word-break;
font-family:'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
}
#square{
width:95%;
height:4px;
border-top:10px solid black;
margin:0 auto;
}
img{
margin:0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Please isolate more the problem in your jsFiddle.
Maybe try absolute positionning :

HTML:

```
<div class="centered">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%; left: 20%; right: 20%; bottom: 20%;
}
```

Check that here : http://jsfiddle.net/h6253/6/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `margin:0 auto;` in the body of your CSS:

> body {
>   margin:0 auto;
>   }

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6253/8/).

I have changed a few things such as rather than using h1, h2 etc, I've changed it to `<span>`. This means that the text tags are free to be used for normal text and paragraphs.

Also rather than using the square div I have underlined your name. Unfortunately this has changed the colour of some of the underline but you can take it out if you would prefer to use a div.

Also I have used percentages to get it to change depending on the size of the window.